# Rails application extremely slow on macOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, puma, macos-mojave

Since few weeks I have a problem with my rails application.
First of all, I have to precise that I have this problem only with one application, but this same application runs very well on the computer of my colleagues (with similar performances) and in staging environment, on server.

When I say extremely slow, it's VERY extremely slow. Sometimes, a simple ajax request sometimes takes more than 5 seconds. When I click on the logo to go to the root page, there is a latency of several seconds between the click and the beginning of load. Every page change takes at least 5 seconds...

This is my development.rb:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Highlight code that triggered database queries in logs.
  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = false
  config.assets.digest = false

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  # config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: '0.0.0.0', port: '3000' }
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://0.0.0.0:3000'
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'localhost',
    port:    1025
  }

  config.after_initialize do
    Bullet.enable = true
    Bullet.console = true
    Bullet.alert = true
  end
end
```

There was no change in my configuration that could have caused this problem. It appears on Firefox, Chrome and Safari and each browser are up to date.

On the other hand my Mac had a strange behavior shortly after the appearance of the problem and rebooted with a very long load, like an update (but it was not) and with a configuration of US keyboard (it had never done it) and some local gems that did not exist anymore (like Rails itself, capistrano, rspec...) so I don't know if it's related.

**The strange fact is that:**

For example, an ajax request takes 2600ms in Chrome benchmark. In the benchmark, scripting, rendering, painting and other takes ~ 90ms and Idle takes ~ 2510ms.

If I check the logs, I have this:
`Completed 200 OK in 228ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 27.7ms)`

The completed status is rendered in the logs after the loading (so more than 2 seconds) but the time indicated is similar to that in staging or on my friend laptop, like if there's no problem.

So I don't know where to look, of course I emptied the cache, restarted the server and my computer, tried to change the development environment configuration (no noticeable change)...

It's like if the problem did not come from the rails server but rather between the server and the browser (because in the benchmark, 'idle' takes a very long time), but I do not know enough to know what it could be.

I must also clarify that for the MacOS activity monitor everything is OK and that there is no saturation (inactive CPU is around 70% and I have more than 3.5Gb free RAM)

```
Ruby version: 2.5.1p57
Rails version: 5.2.2

Laptop :
  Macbook Pro 2016 macOS Mojave 10.14.3
  2,6 GHz Intel Core i7
  16 Go 2133 MHz LPDDR3
```

Has anyone ever had a similar problem? That could be a problem with puma and if yes, how to know?

Comment: I would recommend patching up to the latest stable patch version of Ruby and Rails. Additionally you can look through the [release notes](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/releases/) to see if this is a known issue that has already been resolved. If the issue is not resolved in the latest stable patch please update this question with your findings

Comment: Hi Steven, the problem disappeared by itself without any update, it bothers me not to know what was at the origin, but at least it is corrected and the problem didn't arise again